# How can i avoid negative number through input or if user input negative number the program gives bug result?

Tags: c

> Everytime user gives input two values. The result should be ,result = (large number/ small number) always.
>   if user gives a negative and a positive value as a input then it produces a bug.
>   [image]

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

int times=0;
float a,b,result;

while(times<5)
{
    printf("\nEnter two numbers : \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    if(a =< 0 || b =< 0)
    {
        printf("INPUT ERROR\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(a>=b)
        {
            result =a/b;
            printf("The result is = %.2f\n",result);
        }
        else
        {
            result =b/a;
            printf("The result is = %.2f\n",result);
        }
    }

    times++;
}
return 0;
}
```

how can i fix this problem.thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: There is no such operator as `=<`.  Are you ignoring warnings and errors from your compiler?

Comment: C or C++? Your code doesn't compile either way. Please show us your real code otherwise we can't effectively help.

Comment: The code is written in C.

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warnings.  Review. `scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code: operators and handling input.

If you want to check whether something is less/equal to something else you should use `<=` or `>=`, while you are using the `=<` operator, which in (at least) C/C++ does not exist.

When it comes to getting the input and your usage of `float` variables, you should use the same placeholder as in `printf`, which for `float` variables is `%f`. If you decided to change it to `int`, you would use `%d`, but then your result will be also `int`.

Fixed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int times = 0;
    float a, b, result;

    while (times < 5)
    {
        printf("\nEnter two numbers : \n");
        scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
        if(a <= 0 || b <= 0)
        {
            printf("INPUT ERROR\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if(a >= b)
            {
                result = a / b;
                printf("The result is = %.2f\n", result);
            }
            else
            {
                result = b / a;
                printf("The result is = %.2f\n", result);
            }
        }
        times++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also a tip for compiling the code - use extra flags, which will always show you error, I really like using `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`. They give information about "questionable" constructions (`-Wall`), enable even more flags which are not enabled by `-Wall` (`-Wextra`), change all warnings into errors (`-Werror`) and issue all the warnings demanded by ISO C (`-pedantic`).

Comment: @Jewel if you find the answer helpful, you can 'tick' it, so other people now that you do not need help with the problem anymore.

Comment: sir i have a problem also.i want to divide 10/-5=-2

Comment: You should allow `b` variable to be negative, thus you should change your if statement for checking `a` and `b` values just for checking `a` value: `if (a <= 0 && b != 0)`. Remember you cannot divide the number by 0.